# Error using ggplot2 facet_grid: 'as_tibble' not an expected object from 'namespace:tibble'

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I'm attempting to run the following code:

```
ggplot(weather, aes(fake_date, Mean.TemperatureF, group = Year, color = Year)) +
  geom_line(size = 1, alpha = 0.4) + 
  geom_line(data = mean_df, alpha = 1, size = 1.5,
            aes(fake_date, five_yr_mean, group = mean, color = mean)) + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("months"), labels = date_format("%b")) + 
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Temperature (F)",
       title = "Seattle Daily Temperature, 2012-2016") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  facet_grid(Year ~ .)
```

When I run all of the code without the `+ facet_grid(Year ~ .)` part, the result is what I expect. When I run the code with `+ facet_grid(Year ~ .)` included, I get the following error message:

> Error: 'as_tibble' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tibble'

The only possible solution I could find through Google-searching this error was to install the `tibble` and `plotly` packages. I did so, but I'm still getting the same error message. Thanks in advance for any suggestions you may have!

**Edit (adding more R Output)**

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United     States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252     LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] plotly_3.6.0        tibble_1.0          readr_0.2.2             purrr_0.2.2         tidyr_0.5.1        
 [6] scales_0.4.1        dplyr_0.5.0         lubridate_1.5.6         ggplot2_2.2.0       RevoUtilsMath_8.0.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.5      magrittr_1.5     munsell_0.4.3    colorspace_1.2-6     R6_2.1.2         httr_1.2.0      
 [7] stringr_1.0.0    plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.3.1      grid_3.3.1           gtable_0.2.0     DBI_0.4-1       
[13] htmltools_0.3.5  lazyeval_0.2.0   assertthat_0.1   digest_0.6.9         gridExtra_2.2.1  viridis_0.3.4   
[19] base64enc_0.1-3  htmlwidgets_0.6  rsconnect_0.4.3  labeling_0.3         stringi_1.1.1    RevoUtils_10.0.1
[25] jsonlite_0.9.22 

> devtools::session_info()

Session info -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (0.99.903)          
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/Los_Angeles         
 date     2017-01-09                  

Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package       * version date       source                            
 assertthat      0.1     2013-12-06 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 base64enc       0.1-3   2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
 colorspace      1.2-6   2015-03-11 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 DBI             0.4-1   2016-05-08 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 devtools        1.12.0  2016-06-24 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 digest          0.6.9   2016-01-08 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 dplyr         * 0.5.0   2016-06-24 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 ggplot2       * 2.2.0   2016-11-11 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                    
 gridExtra       2.2.1   2016-02-29 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 gtable          0.2.0   2016-02-26 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 htmltools       0.3.5   2016-03-21 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 htmlwidgets     0.6     2016-02-25 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 httr            1.2.0   2016-06-15 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 jsonlite        0.9.22  2016-06-15 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 labeling        0.3     2014-08-23 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
 lazyeval        0.2.0   2016-06-12 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 lubridate     * 1.5.6   2016-04-06 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 magrittr        1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 memoise         1.0.0   2016-01-29 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 munsell         0.4.3   2016-02-13 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 plotly        * 3.6.0   2016-05-18 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 plyr            1.8.4   2016-06-08 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 purrr         * 0.2.2   2016-06-18 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 R6              2.1.2   2016-01-26 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 Rcpp            0.12.5  2016-05-14 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 readr         * 0.2.2   2015-10-22 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 RevoUtils       10.0.1  2016-08-24 local                             
 RevoUtilsMath * 8.0.3   2016-04-13 local                             
 rsconnect       0.4.3   2016-11-02 Github (rstudio/rsconnect@1665cb8)
 scales        * 0.4.1   2016-11-09 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                    
 stringi         1.1.1   2016-05-27 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
 stringr         1.0.0   2015-04-30 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 tibble        * 1.0     2016-03-23 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
 tidyr         * 0.5.1   2016-06-14 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 viridis         0.3.4   2016-03-12 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                    
 withr           1.0.2   2016-06-20 CRAN (R 3.3.1)
```

Comment: output of `sessionInfo()` or `devtools::session_info()` will help. Did you fully restart the R session after the package installs?

Comment: you can add it as a code block to the question

Comment: @hrbrmstr - I've deleted my replies to your initial comment and added the output to the original question; thanks!

Comment: current tibble pkg version is 1.2. I'd remove.packages it and try reinstalling.